# Modulo coordinate issues (% in C#)

Tags: c#, xna, coordinates, modulo

In my tile-based game the world is split into 32x32 tile chunks. They span in all directions, so there are chunks at positions below zero. Tile images are drawn onto 1024x1024 texture2Ds attached to each chunk. I need to be able to use modulo correctly with negative coordintates to basically convert game-world coords to coords on the texture.

The following doesn't work, coords are obviously going to be reversed if they are negative. (i.e. (-32, -32) would be (-32, -32) instead of (992, 992))

```
   public int mod(int num)
   {
       //Mods a pixel position to fit in a chunk texture
       return Math.Abs(num % 1024);
   }
```

What do I do? I need something that works.

I tried this as well:

```
    public int mod(int num)
    {
        //Mods a pixel position to fit in a chunk texture
        if (num < 0)
            return (num % 1024) + 1024;
        else
            if (num >= 0)
                return num % 1024;
            else return -1;
    }
```

...which eliminates the reversal issue, but if the coordinate is -1024 or similar, it becomes 0 at the modulo and ends up 1024, which is out of bounds of the texture...

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing with my game, in order to get the correct coordinates you need to do:

```
public int PerformRepeatLogic(int x)
{
    //Mods a pixel position to fit in a chunk texture
    int result = Math.Abs(x) % 1024;

    if (x < 0)
        result = 1024 - result;
    return result;
}
```

With this you can easily do `x = PerformRepeatLogic(x)` to "loop" your coordinates properly. (Ex: With a width of `1000`, `-5` will become `995`)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. (-1024, -1024) still equals (1024, 1024) instead of (0, 0)

Comment: What do you mean (i.e. (-32, -32) would be (-32, -32) instead of (992, 992))? I think I might have misunderstood you.

Comment: Using your method with a Width of 1024, (-32, -32) = (992, 992), (-512, -512) = (512, 512), and (-1024, -1024) = (1024, 1024) I need (-1024, -1024) to equal (0, 0)

Comment: Can't you achieve that by simply doing `1024 % 1024`? Where the first 1024 is your X position and the second is the width?

Comment: I ment -1024 % 1024, and that is not the case, https://www.google.com/search?q=1024+%25+1024

Comment: Ah nevermind, in C# it is the case, not in regular mathematics :P

Comment: Ack! What do I do, then?!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50995/discussion-between-cyral-and-lemoncreme) I'm trying to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

In your problem case, you just need to mod it again, i.e. making 1024 = 0 [(code)](http://ideone.com/eQgobF):

```
static double calc(double num)
{
    double mod = num % 1024;
    return mod < 0 ? (1024 + mod) % 1024 : mod;
}
```